# How to display an image in vuejs/vuetify whose path is in json fake server?

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js, vuetify.js

how do I display an image whose path is in a json fake server? Data in json file looks like:

```
"packages": [
{
...
    "images": [
        "https://i.ibb.co/g7FWSYv/a.jpg", 
        "https://i.ibb.co/hX3xQ5K/b.jpg", 
        "https://i.ibb.co/68TdBNs/c.jpg"
      ],
...
},
]
```

I am using a v-for loop to display data

```
<v-col v-for="(package, index) in packages" :key="index">
    <v-img :src="package.images[0]" ></v-img>
</v-col>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            packages: [],
        }
    },
    created () {
      this.initialize()
    },
    methods: {
        initialize () {
            axios.get('http://localhost:4000/packages', {})
            .then(response => { 
                this.packages = response.data
            })
        }
    }
}
```

But the image is not getting displayed. I am getting an error in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

response.data is correct. It is showing the images array with 3 elements.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

I have changed my json slightly:

```
 "images": [
    { "src": "https://i.ibb.co/g7FWSYv/a.jpg"}, 
    { "src": "https://i.ibb.co/hX3xQ5K/b.jpg" }, 
    { "src": "https://i.ibb.co/68TdBNs/c.jpg"}
  ],
```

and changed the code as:

```
<v-img :src="package.images[0].src"></v-img>
```

Still I am getting the same error in console.log()

Comment: Is `response.data` correct ? What is the value of `c` (btw, you should really give it a more meaningful name...) ? Please provide necessary info if you want some answer.

Comment: Hello Pierre, I think the response.data is correct. I have edited my question.

Comment: It might be due to the template being rendered before `initialise()` resolves. Try to add a condition to the `v-img` like `<v-img v-if="package && package.images" :src="package.images[0]" ></v-img>`.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the data structure of `response.data` if it's an array of objects that contains `images` field as an array of images links, then your code should work.
if `response.data` is a single object (which I presume) that contains `images` array then `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` will be rised, in this case you don't need a loop to show your 0 indexed images, just

```
<v-img v-if="packages.images" :src="packages.images[0]" ></v-img>
```